# Electricity needed to maintain power for camera

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, discharge

I am not an electrical engineer by any means and do not even know the terms I should use to ask this question but basically I am trying to determine which solar panel I can use to power my camera.

- I am not looking to charge it insomuch as the camera will be in operation while the solar is hooked up to it.
- Let's assume the solar power is perfectly consistent and no loss in transit. (I know it is not but I will just double the final numbers to give some flexibility).
- The Camera is rated at 1030mAH, 3.8V, 3.23Wh (it's a gopro 4 session)

My understanding (limited) is that to charge a battery, I need to basically match the amperage and voltage (assuming a perfect connection) but how does this work if the battery to charge is also being drained simultaneously? Is there a formula specific to this?

My maths suggests that I need at minimum a 1030mA and a 3.8volt solar charger... To scale this up (to account for solar charging fluctuations) do I simply increases the amps but **not** the voltage or is both ok to increase?

Also, what is the wiggle room on voltage? I found a charger for 3.7 volts but not 3.8 and am wondering if that is ok.

Comment: So say in the first bullet point you are not looking to charge it, and then in the last paragraph you found a charger and wondering if that is okay.  ????

Comment: 1030mAh and 1030mA are two very different things. It will help your understanding if you learn the difference between Amps and Amp-hours.

Comment: How long will the camera run from a fully charged battery? That will guide us how much current it needs.

Comment: @tcrosley, yes that is what I said. I also do not understand all the terms fully so bare with me a little.

Comment: @DanLaks, this seems to be the missing link or at least a huge part, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @BrianDrummond, Absolutely right! There are various charts but the battery life is around 1.5-2hrs thus the operation of the device pulls between ~515mA and ~686mA an hour.

Comment: No, it pulls 515 mA to 686 mA.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, it pulls that per hour though right or is that constant?

Comment: It's a constant. It would be valid to say, it takes 515mAh per hour. But silly, since 515 mA means the same.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. So basically, I need to find a solar charger that provides at least 515mA.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a few misconceptions about the GoPro's battery and how power is supplied to the GoPro itself. I'll try to clear those up and then explain how you can do what you're trying to do.

In your third bullet point, you claim the camera is rated at 1030mAh and 3.8V. Those numbers are actually referring to the nominal voltage and charge capacity of the GoPro's *battery*, not the camera itself. The unit mAh (pronounced milli-Amp-hour), or just Ah, is used to describe how much capacity a battery has. It is not a measurement of instantaneous current (Amps). The different between Amps and Amp-hours trips up a lot of beginners and it's worth spending some time understanding the difference.

So why does this matter? Well, the GoPro is a sophisticated piece of consumer electronics. It's designed to maintain and charge its own battery. You don't need to worry about charging the battery yourself. It already contains all of the circuitry internally to do that for you. All you need to do is provide it with the voltage it *expects* to get from the outside world. After some quick Googling, I see that the GoPro expects to be plugged into a USB cable. That's a good thing! USB voltage is a very common 5VDC. You just need to provide a steady 5V source and the GoPro will do the rest.

The only unknown that's left is how much current the GoPro will draw while operating. The worst case scenario is a fully depleted battery and recording video at a high resolution. These two conditions combined will result in the largest current draw from the 5V source. It looks like someone did an [interesting experiment](http://cam-do.com/GoProPower.html) to discover the power consumption of various GoPros in various different modes. Using the information in that website, it looks like the high-end of current draw is about 1A. Add a little extra current in case the battery is charging and let's round up to 1.5A*.

We have the voltage and approximate current, which is enough to calculate the power consumption of the GoPro while recording video and possibly charging the battery from a 5V source:
$$P=VI=(5V)(1.5A)=7.5W$$
Now you know how big the solar panel needs to be. But there's still one more thing you need to consider. The solar panel won't output exactly 5V. In fact, the voltage will vary with the sun intensity over the course of the day. But the GoPro needs a steady 5V or you risk damaging your expensive camera.

The solution is to pick a solar panel that generates a voltage higher than 5V. For example, 12V solar panels are very common and easy to find. You then connect the output of the solar panel into a high-efficiency voltage regulator that converts the voltage down to 5V. Now you've got a steady, regulated 5V to plug into your GoPro. Even if the 12V solar panel varies over the course of the day, the regulator will adjust to keep its output at 5V.

Obviously once the sun starts to set or if it's too cloudy, all bets are off on the regulator's ability to maintain the necessary voltage. You'll need to come up with some solution to prevent an under-voltage condition. But that's beyond the scope of this answer.

*I'm applying an educated guess to come up with this number. There are a large number of unknown variables about the internal circuity of a GoPro that could render this number completely wrong.

Comment: Sweet thank you for this! There are two big things I was missing. My misconception of mAH vs mA and the voltage regulator... Thank you for the link too although with the GoPro session, it draws significantly less power than the other ones. As an aside, what does the mAH rating of a solar charger mean? I havent found any that are 1030mAH with all being far more than that (like 10k+) what effect does this have?

Comment: I'd be surprised if a solar charger advertises a mAh rating. Solar panels don't store charge, so they don't have a charge capacity rating. It's like turning on your kitchen faucet and asking "how many buckets of water does this faucet have in it?" It's a nonsensical question. Your faucet supplies water for as long as you leave it on. Similarly, a solar panel will provide current for as long as it has sunlight. How much charge it transports only depends on how long you leave it connected.

Comment: Perhaps provide a link to the solar panel you're looking at and maybe we can see where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but when you look on amazon (http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=solar+charger) the top results all have a mAH rating in their titles...

Comment: Ah, because those are solar panels *combined* with a battery. The mAh rating is describing the battery within the product, not the solar panel.

Comment: That makes sense. I've learned so much in asking this question alone!

Answer (score 1):

The GoPro Session uses a USB power supply. USB is rated at 500mA, 4.75V to 5.25V.

To run the Camera off a Solar Panel, you need an open-circuit voltage in the range 4.75V to 5.25V.  Any more than 5.25V, you might damage the camera. Any less than 4.75V, the operating voltage will be less than 4.75V.

That is not a 5V solar panel. A 5V solar panel has a maximum power point around 5V, and an open-circuit voltage around 6V.  6V may not damage your camera, but at around $400, do you want to find out?

If you can't find a 500mA 5.25V o/c panel, you should regulate the voltage, to keep it around 5V. You can buy or make a regulator to do this: a simple car power adapter (cigarette lighter adapter) might work.

Note that if you want to "charge the battery" outside of the camera, you need a battery charger. The lithium ion battery in the go-pro should not be directly connected to a solar cell.

Comment: This is good info about the warnings of my methods. Where did you find the USB rating info for the GoPro?

Answer (score 1):

The GoPro Hero 4 Session has a lithium-ion battery. When fully charged it should be about 4.2V. However this is not your concern because you cannot charge the battery directly from a solar panel. To ensure that the battery is charged correctly you should use the supplied USB charger.

The camera is supposed to record for at least 1.5 hours on its 1030mAh battery, so it should draw less than 690mA (1.03Ah / 1.5 hours). According to the charger's instructions it may take up to 2 hours to charge the battery from a 5V 1A supply. This suggests that it is charging at less than 1A, so when the camera is operating most of the current will be running the camera and the battery will charge slowly if at all.

Your solar panel should be able to keep the camera running continuously *provided* that it can supply at least 1A *and* at a well regulated +5V. In other words, what you need is a regulator that converts the output of your solar panel to the equivalent of a 5V 1A power supply.

> I found a charger for 3.7 volts but not 3.8 and am wondering if that
>   is ok.

No. You should only use the supplied charger, as it is matched to the battery in the camera. A charger rated at 3.7V is *probably* designed for Lithium cells that charge up to 4.2V, but you cannot be sure that it will be safe for your battery. Also the camera may have an internal charging circuit, and its 'charger' could actually just be a power supply.